# UISearchBar crashing when typing a character in the plist

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uisearchdisplaycontroller

The Search bar crashes when i search for a character in the plist i have created. it doesn't crash if a letter doesn't exist. not sure whats going wrong, if anyone can help i would appreciate it, thanks.

Heres the code

```
viewController.h

@interface ViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchDisplayDelegate, 
UISearchBarDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *authors;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *searchResults;


@property IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchBar;



@end 



viewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MTBookCoverViewController.h"
#import "MTBooksViewController.h"
#import "Cell.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController{


}

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
 {
 self = [super initWithStyle:style];
 if (self) {

 }
 return self;
 }

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Set Title
self.title = @"Authors";

// Load Property List
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Books" ofType:@"plist"];
self.authors = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSLog(@"authors > %@", self.authors);

self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.authors count]];

}

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
// Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[self.searchResults removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c]   %@",searchText];
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.authors filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];

[[self tableView] reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
// Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:  [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
// Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

 #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
//#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
//#warning Incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of rows in the section.
//return 0;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [self.searchResults count];

} else {
   return [self.authors count];

}

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

Cell *cell = (Cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (Cell == nil) {
    Cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

    Cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    //from the plist
    NSDictionary *author = [self.authors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    [cell.label setText:[author objectForKey:@"Author"]];
    [cell.label2 setText:[author objectForKey:@"Cover"]];
    cell.icon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[author objectForKey:@"Cover"]];
}



return cell;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table View Delegate Methods
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Initialize Books View Controller
MTBooksViewController *booksViewController = [[MTBooksViewController alloc] init];

// Fetch and Set Author
NSDictionary *author = [self.authors objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[booksViewController setAuthor:[author objectForKey:@"Author"]];

// Push View Controller onto Navigation Stack
[self.navigationController pushViewController:booksViewController animated:YES];
}

@end
```

heres the plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
 <plist version="1.0">
 <array>
   <dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>w</string>
    <key>Author</key>
    <string>J.R.R. Tolkien</string>
    <key>Cover</key>
    <string>twitter.png</string>
    <key>Books</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>test</string>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>twitter.png</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Fellowship of the Ring</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1954</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>two-towers.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Two Towers</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1954</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>return-king.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Return of the King</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1955</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>bilbo-song.png</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Bilbo&apos;s Last Song</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1966</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>q</string>
    <key>Author</key>
    <string>Dan Brown</string>
    <key>Cover</key>
    <string>fellowship.jpg</string>
    <key>Books</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>digital-fortress.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Digital Fortress</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1998</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>angels-demons.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Angels and Demons</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2000</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>deception-point.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Deception Point</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2001</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>da-vinci-code.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Da Vinci Code</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2003</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>lost-symbol.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Lost Symbol</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2009</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>w</string>
    <key>Author</key>
    <string>J.K. Rowling</string>
    <key>Cover</key>
    <string>fellowship.jpg</string>
    <key>Books</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>stone.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Philosopher&apos;s Stone</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1997</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>chamber.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1998</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>azkaban.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1999</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>goblet.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2000</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>phoenix.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2003</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>prince.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Half Blood Prince</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2005</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>hallows.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2007</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>bard.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>The Tales of Beedle the Bard</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2008</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>s</string>
    <key>Author</key>
    <string>Robin Cook</string>
    <key>Cover</key>
    <string>fellowship.jpg</string>
    <key>Books</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>sphinx.jpeg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Sphinx</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1979</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>brain.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Brain</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1981</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>fever.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Fever</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1982</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>blindsight.png</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Blindsight</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1992</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>fatal-cure.jpeg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Fatal Cure</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1994</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>invasion.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Invasion</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>1997</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>shock.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Shock</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2001</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>Cover</key>
            <string>intervention.jpg</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Intervention</string>
            <key>Year</key>
            <string>2009</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
   </array>
   </plist>
```

this is the exception i get:

```
2013-10-23 06:22:44.111 tabnav[20102:a0b] -[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109374b60
2013-10-23 06:22:44.181 tabnav[20102:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x109374b60'

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101895795 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001015f8991 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101926bad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010188709d ___forwarding___ + 973
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101886c48 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00000001011efb6b -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:] + 46
    6   Foundation                          0x00000001011f0646 -[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithString:attributes:] + 249
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001003d38a7 -[UILabel _setText:] + 85
    8   tabnav                              0x0000000100004c8a -[ViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 506
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010032c13a -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 348
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000100313fc6 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2297
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010031e728 -[UITableView _visibleCells] + 29
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000100325c12 -[UITableView _scrollFirstResponderCellToVisible:] + 82
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010032ea59 -[UITableView _adjustForAutomaticKeyboardInfo:animated:lastAdjustment:] + 88
    14  UIKit                               0x0000000100583cf7 -[UISearchDisplayController _setTableViewVisible:inView:] + 895
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000100261a8a -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 104
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000100261a20 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 17
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010033591c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 203
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010086bfd4 -[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 198
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000100877660 -[UITextInputController _sendDelegateChangeNotificationsForText:selection:] + 102
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000100878e85 -[UITextInputController _insertText:fromKeyboard:] + 450
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000100879652 -[UITextInputController insertText:] + 301
    22  UIKit                               0x00000001003fd8e0 -[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] + 82
    23  Foundation                          0x000000010126f9e4 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 623
    24  UIKit                               0x00000001003fc387 -[UIKeyboardImpl performOperations:] + 148
    25  UIKit                               0x00000001003fa9b7 __73-[UIKeyboardImpl replyHandlerForHandleKeyboardInputWithExecutionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 40
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010088d9d6 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 329
    27  Foundation                          0x00000001011fe6f7 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 227
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101824e61 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101824732 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001018405bf __CFRunLoopRun + 767
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010183fed3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    32  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001039763a4 GSEventRunModal + 161
    33  UIKit                               0x0000000100260a63 UIApplicationMain + 1010
    34  tabnav                              0x0000000100002643 main + 115
    35  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000101f237e1 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: What exception is raised? Please mention it as well as stack trace.

Comment: Hi anum90, thanks for your help to start with.  Do you mean the error i get?

Comment: your stack trace shows that exception is raised when table is being loaded. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` where you are setting text for your label, make sure you have got something in `searchResults`.

Comment: remove irrelevant code from your post.. there are many things in this post which are irrelevant..
Add exception breakpoint in your project and see exactly at which line your code crashes. The reason of your crash is you are accessing a dictionary object as an array.

Comment: how do i go about changing from an array to an object? thanks for the help

Comment: managed to figure it out thanks alot of everyones help and advice :)